# ArcObjects - Interacting with existing ArcGIS Server layer

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-server, arcobjects

I have a bunch of users running a 10.2.1 VB.Net extension, which assumes they have a particular MXD loaded. That MXD contains an existing ArcGIS Server layer (ie. not added programmatically by the extension):

[image: layer Properties]

I can get an `ILayer` reference to that layer using `IMap.Layer([idx])`, but the returned COM object does not seem to support any other interface. Casting it to `IMapServerLayer`, `IMapServerGroupLayer`, `IMapServerSubLayer` etc all return Nothing.

What interfaces should this object support, and how do I get a more useful object than `ILayer` out of it? (eg. to be able to perform spatial queries on it?)

Edit: I had a crack at [this sample](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//00490000005w000000):

```
Dim uidMapServerLayer As New ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UID()
uidMapServerLayer.Value = "{E9B56157-7EB7-4DB3-9958-AFBF3B5E1470}" ' IMapServerLayer GUID

Dim enLayers As IEnumLayer = pMap.Layers(uidMapServerLayer, True)
enLayers.Reset()
Dim eLayer As ILayer = enLayers.Next
While Not eLayer Is Nothing
    Dim eMSLLayer As IMapServerLayer = eLayer
    eLayer = enLayers.Next          ' <-- breakpoint here
End While
```

...and `eMSLLayer` is a valid object. But if I break it at the breakpoint line and execute `CType(eLayer, IMapServerLayer)` I get `Cannot convert to 'Interface IMapServerLayer'`...(this was what I was using to test if the `ILayer` object supported the various interfaces, so apparently I'm barking up the wrong tree)

Comment: Try casting to a IMapServerGroupLayer first and if you can pull the sub-layers from there. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000009pz000000

Comment: Nope - doesn't support that one either. I've tried pretty much every I[something]Layer interface I can find, and the only interface I can find that it supports is `ILayer`.

Comment: See edit....I think I'm driving myself nuts. :(